# Jest Testing in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am having trouble getting my tests to cover this code, I know this is going to be a simple fix once its done but currently I cannot think of how to fix it.

this is the function I have.

```
const AssociateTabs = () => {

  return (

    <AppBar postion="absolute">
      <Tabs>
        <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
          {'Associate Work Dashboard'}
        </Typography>
      </Tabs>
    </AppBar>
  );
};
```

These are currently my tests

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Enzyme, { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';
import AssociateTabs from '../../src/components/AssociateTabs';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('AssociateTabs', () => {
  const AssociateTabs = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = shallow(<AssociateTabs/>);

  it('should match snapshot data', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('should match Associate Tabs', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<AssociateTabs
      Position={'absolute'} variant={'title'} color={'inherit'} 
    />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
   it('should match return', () => {
     const wrapper = shallow(<AssociateTabs />);
     expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();

  });  
 });
```

Comment: Did you post he wrong code? You have jest tests for a component called `<AssociateTabs />` but you have a function component that is called `<JiraData />` How do they relate exactly?

Comment: @aug I fixed it, my bad.

Comment: What seems to be the issue

Comment: @Auriga I need to get my code coverage up but in order to do so I need to write a test that covers the return on Associate tabs.